# Plz send teh iconz: can I get a big ppcg icon?

Tags: support

I'm looking for a big PPCG icon. Where could I get one? The favicon / HNQ icon is too small. Is there something bigger?

Comment: so what exactly is the point in this meta post; to give everyone a free big PPCG icon?

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/img/apple-touch-icon.png

[image: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/img/apple-touch-icon.png]

Bonus: it's transparent.

Comment: +1 for transparent

Comment: +1 for apple touch icon being useful

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't big enough to be vector traced :(